# Installing OE (Order Entry) schema in Oracle Express

Tags: oracle, schema, installation

I'd like to know if it's possible to install OE (Order Entry) schema in Oracle Express. If so, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

SQL should be present in `$ORACLE_HOME/demo/schema/order_entry`.

This link gives all the info:

[Oracle 11g Release 1 Database Sample Schemas](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28328/installation.htm)

It can be downloaded from:

[Sample Models and Scripts](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/datamodeler/sample-models-scripts-224531.html)

Comment: This schema is not present in 12c database. Have to install it.